# Application stats are completely broken.

Tags: bug, statistics

It appears that the application stats are completely broken. Attempting to view the number of times Stack Mobile hit the `/questions/*` methods results in this graph:

[image]

It would seem that statistics were either not kept after about November 1 or there is some glitch with displaying them.

Comment: Seeing the same problem.  Stats are reporting zero traffic.